# Why does my browser not display the index.html file when I type a directory in the URL?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, html, redirection

I have a folder containing a web page `index.html` that redirects to another page. When I type in the browser the URL of that directory without specifying a file name, I expect it to open the `index.html` which redirects to the intended page. But when I open a directory in any of my browsers (Chrome, Firefox), the directory structure/tree is shown instead:

```
Index of C:\Users\User1\Documents\
[parent directory]
```

Why doesn't the browser open the index.html file? I am using Windows 7.

Comment: You need to provide more information. This is not a browser issue. This is a configuration issue, with what I presume is IIS. First disable directory listing, and then make sure the default document is set.

Comment: How do I disable directory listing?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx - its similar in iis 8 probably. It's been a while since I played with this stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Because you are accessing it with a `file://` reference and it is not being served by a webserver.

The fact that you can go to a directory and get a default file is part of the webserver config - Apache has the `DirectoryIndex` directive which often specifies multiple files (index.htm, index.html, index.php, etc), from what I recall IIS uses "Default.htm"

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't the browser open the index.html file?

As pointed out in the comments, the two most likely causes are:

- Having directory listings enabled (which show individual files in a directory).
- Having your default page association(s) (often referred to as *default documents*) configured incorrectly (e.g. you are using *index.html* when the server is only configured to recognize *index.htm* files as valid default web pages).

**IIS**

If you are using IIS, there should be an option called Directory Browsing in the central IIS Manager window (the Features View pane). Note that you must select a "level" (a server or site instance in the left-hand window) before this option appears. Once selected for a given level, you can toggle Directory Browsing in the right-hand window (the Actions pane) via Enable/Disable. This can be done server-wide, for individual sites or even specific directories.

To configure default document settings in IIS, right-click the site or folder then click Properties. Select the Documents tab and click the "Enable Default Document" check box if it isn't already selected. You can add a new default document by clicking Add. In the Default Document Name box, type the name of the default document (e.g. *index.html*) and click OK when finished. Note that it is possible to have more than one default document (e.g. *index.htm* and *index.html*). You can change the order of preference (what IIS looks for first) if you wish.

**Apache**

In httpd.conf (or wherever appropriate), you will want to remove the *Indexes* parameter for any *Options* directive to disable directory listings. To specify your default document(s), look for the applicable *DirectoryIndex* directive and specify the appropriate name(s) in a list e.g.

```
DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php home.php foo.bar
```